# Is there a way to limit Spotify's upstream P2P traffic?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bandwidth, p2p, spotify

As indicated [here](http://www.geekwire.com/2011/practical-nerd-hidden-price-free), Spotify slyly uses my bandwidth to provide other users with the service. Is there a way to limit the upstream traffic from Spotify so that my non-unlimited bandwidth is conserved?

I regularly run both Windows 7 and Ubuntu and I know that I can't entirely block upstream traffic, but I would like to limit it to ~30-50 kbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from Spotify.

There are ways to do that with other software, however: Ubuntu has for example [trickle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/trickle.1.html) and Windows has [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Comment: I'm looking into how to do this on a Mac, and can't find a program that nicely identifies and allows you to limit specific services. If I want to use a program that will let me throttle specific ports, which ports should I throttle for spotify's upstream traffic?

Comment: @JayNeely https://support.spotify.com/fi/learn-more/faq/#!/article/How-to-open-network-ports-to-allow-Spotify

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to limit this traffic with your router's Quality of Service function if there is such.